# Hash Table in r5rs

Tags: data-structures, scheme, dynamic-programming

I am solving a problem on project euler requiring dynamic programming, and in this particular instance, it is cleaner to use a hash table over a dynamic programming "solutions" table. Using r5rs, what functions are available to me to create my own hash table? how might i best go about constructing and using one? it's a hash table of integers.

Comment: Are you looking for hash tables in the r5rs standard itself, or rather hash table libraries that are implemented using the r5rs language?

Comment: I'm looking for how one would best approach a home-brewed solution of hash tables in r5rs, if indeed it is not in the standard. If there are good library solutions (that work on most or all r5rs scheme implementations), I would love to hear about them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [SFRI 69: Basic hash tables](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html), which includes a [reference implementation](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-69/srfi-69.html#mplm) that is nearly pure R5RS.

Comment: Using *pure* R5RS for real problems is not easy to do, since the language is tiny.  It's better if you go with whatever your implementation provides.  It'll likely be much faster too.

Comment: Yes, I'd also recommend using implementation-specific libraries where possible. The question and followup makes me think that there's a premium on portability here, though.